# AngularJS <select> with ng-model and ng-options gets broken on element delete

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a selector in v1.3.0-beta.3:

```
<select 
ng-model='selectedPassport'
ng-change="selectPassport(selectedPassport)"
ng-options="passport.number for passport in passports"
required>
</select>
```

I have a button with ng-click to delete element from passports array:

```
    // delete button handler
    $scope.deletePassport = function () {
      var delIdx = $scope.passports.indexOf($scope.selectedPassport);

      var idx = delIdx;
      if (idx > 0) {
        idx--;
      }
      $scope.passports.splice(delIdx,1);
      $scope.selectedPassport = $scope.passports[idx];
   };

   // if I don't do that, I wouldn't be able to use $selectedPassport in my code
   $scope.selectPassport = function (pass) { 
      $scope.selectedPassport = pass; 
   }
```

I want to make previous passport to be selected after deleting current passport. But instead of that I get empty passport selected. In DOM model it corresponds to option with value="?", though ng-model points to valid elemnt in ng-options. How can I overcome this?

Comment: did you check if your delIdx contains the expected value?

Comment: What does ng-change do?

Comment: delIdx contains what I need, I tested this in debugger, idx is correct and array after slice is also correct.

Comment: @Dalorzo, I've added ng-change code

Comment: I posted a working plunker, basically just copied your first question and it worked. You do NOT need the selectPassport method as ng-model already holds a reference to your selected passport

Comment: Dear @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck, if I remove selectPassport then $scope.selectedPassport points to a wrong passport. For example if i have passports 1,2,3, I select 2, but 1st is deleted. I don't know why. This is another angular bug/feature.

Comment: @stiv Did you try my plunker? It works as i understand your problem. If i select 2 in the list and hit delete, the dropdown points to 1 (and removes entry 2, leaving only empty, 1 and 3)?

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: Dear @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck, I've seen your sample and it works even with ng-change. My interface is a bit more complex, i've put here only part of code that i considered to be problematic. So I don't know why it works in punker and doesn't work in my system. I'll try to simplify my code and isolate the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by ng-if= attribute that presented in this element. I didn't put ng-if into source example, because I thought that it is not related to the issue. Each time deletePassport() was invoked, ng-if condition was recalculated automatically by angular and select element was recreated and thus lost selection. Solved by replacing ng-if with ng-show.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$scope.selectedPassport` is going to be an object, and in this case `indexOx` in this expression

```
var delIdx = $scope.passports.indexOf($scope.selectedPassport);
```

will fail to find a corresponding array index. I think you can fix it this way:

```
$scope.deletePassport = function() {

    var delIdx = -1;

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.passports.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.passports[i].number === $scope.selectedPassport.number) {
            delIdx = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (delIdx > -1) {
        $scope.passports.splice(delIdx, 1);
        $scope.selectedPassport = $scope.passports[delIdx];
    }
};
```

Proof of concept: http://plnkr.co/edit/E1BAwS6JHGzQs4gMct7R?p=preview

Comment: @stiv I see. Try to remove `ng-change="selectPassport(selectedPassport)"`, you don't need this function since you have `ngModel` defined.

Comment: Your proof of concept has the same problem as i have: after deleting, no default value is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I made your example into a Plunker example and it seems to be working. You must have forgotten something or messed up your Delete button?

http://plnkr.co/edit/Rs173vmhu1bBubvRS18j